# Bug (??) in formatting long values with CString::Format

Tags: c++, format, long-integer, c-strings

I have issues with the following code:

```
CString cstr;
cstr.Format("SELECT foobar %ld, %ld ",  
    " AND type = '%s' ",
    1426233870,1426243870, "'OR'");
```

The resulting CString contains wrong numbers!

The code is simplified, actually I am selecting datasets from a database between two timestamps in seconds.

I was able to solve my problem by formatting two Strings and appending the second at the end of the first, so I do not need an answer. But if sombody could confirm that this is a bug in CString::Format, this may preserve other people from loosing as many nerves as I did ...

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is MFC, it should be like this:

```
CString cstr;
cstr.Format("SELECT 123=%ld, 456=%ld AND type = '%s' ", 123, 456, "'type'");
```

It's like printf.

Comment: In this format the code works; it seems to be possible but not allowed to break the format string in several comma separated pieces. Thank you.